# ionic firebase phone authentication The SMS code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic4, angularfire

I am using this plugin for phone authentication.https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-authentication

I have successfully sent the top to mobile numbers, but while retrieving I am getting following error every time

> The SMS code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try
>   again

I also want to auto verify otp(without letting the user to manually enter otp).

I think both issues are interconnected

Here is my code

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { FirebaseAuthentication } from '@ionic-native/firebase-authentication/ngx';

constructor(private router: Router,private fireAuth: AngularFireAuth,public firebaseAuthentication : FirebaseAuthentication) {}

send(){


      this.firebaseAuthentication.verifyPhoneNumber("+91xxxxxxxxxx", 30000).then(credential => {
        alert("code sent")

        console.log(credential)

        if(credential) {

          this.verificationid = credential

          const smsCode = prompt("Enter SMS verification code");

          let cred = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(this.verificationid,smsCode)

          this.fireAuth.signInWithCredential(cred).then(val => {
            console.log(val)
            console.log("successs")
          }).catch(err => console.log(err))

        }
      })
    }
```

Comment: Have you got the success? I am getting the same error with the above method that you had tried.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out to be very simple.

All latest android phones support auto-verify OTP. `verifyPhoneNumber` method auto verifies otp. Thus when we ask the user to enter OTP it gives an error "code expired".

So the solution is on android devices listen to `onAuthStateChanged` method to redirect users after successful phone authentication and for old devices or ios enter otp manually works.

Here is full code

html

```
<div [hidden]="display_otp">

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating"> Enter your mobile number </ion-label>
    <ion-input type="tel" [formControl] = "mobile_no" ></ion-input>

  </ion-item>
  <ion-button [disabled] = "mobile_no.invalid" (click)="Send(mobile_no.value)">Continue</ion-button>
</div>

<div *ngIf="display_otp">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating"> Enter your OTP  </ion-label>
    <ion-input type="tel" [formControl] = "otp" ></ion-input>

  </ion-item>

  <ion-button [disabled] = "otp.invalid" (click)="enter_otp(otp.value)">Submit</ion-button>
</div>
```

.ts

```
constructor(){


this.firebaseAuthentication.onAuthStateChanged().subscribe(user =>{

        if(user) {
          console.log(user)

          console.log("success")
          // OTP verifired. Do success operation
        }
        else {
          console.log("state not changed")
       // wrong otp
        }
      })

}


    Send(mobile_no){
        console.log(mobile_no) 
        let mobile ="+91" + mobile_no
        console.log(mobile)


        this.firebaseAuthentication.verifyPhoneNumber(mobile, 30000).then(credential =>{
          if(credential){

            console.log(credential)
            this.verificationid = credential
            this.display_otp = true

          }
        })


       }  

       enter_otp(otp){
         console.log(otp)

         this.firebaseAuthentication.signInWithVerificationId(this.verificationid, otp).then(user =>{
          if(user) {
            console.log(user)

          }
          else {
            console.log("no user")
          }
        })

       }
```